# How to convert a Fragment layout to a bitmap and send it by email without saving any file (Kotlin 2022)?

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, mobile

I am developing an Android app using Kotlin.
I need to convert a layout (that is actually a report of the user's input data, some views converted to bitmap in imageviews and extra text) and send it by email **as .pdf** when the user clicks on a button inside the fragment (that is the previsualisation of the future PDF) **without saving it**.

I've read and watched hours of tutorials but none is helping (deprecated, old java or saving the file)

I guess I need a function that converts the desired view to a bitmap image, scales it to A4 size format, sets that scaled image to pdf file and returns it so I can then put it as an attachment to mail Intent,not forgetting I am inside a fragment.

I will be updating the post.
Thank you

EDIT : I already know how to convert a layout to bitmap and put it inside an image view (I can share if someone needs). So I only need a function that takes the bitmap as an argument and returns .pdf (or .jpg) and an other one that intents as attachment that returned pdf to send email

Comment: does this mean that i can't do it without saving?

Comment: yes sorry this isnt clear, by saving i mean writing a file in Internal or External storage like every tutorial explains

Answer (score 1):

```
fun getDetailImage(){

    val image=getBitmapFromView(llParent)
    ivShareImage.setImageBitmap(image)
}

private fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap? {

    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    val returnedBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    //Bind a canvas to it
    val canvas=Canvas(returnedBitmap)
    //Get the view's background
    val bgDrawable=view.background
    if (bgDrawable != null) {
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas)
    } else {
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
    }
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas)
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap
}

fun getShareImage(){
    getDetailImage()
    val mDrawable: Drawable=ivShareImage.getDrawable()
    val mBitmap=(mDrawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap

    val path=MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
        appCompatActivity.getContentResolver(),
        mBitmap,
        "image-name",
        null
    )
    val uri: Uri=Uri.parse(path)
    val shareIntent=Intent()
    shareIntent.action=Intent.ACTION_SEND
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
    shareIntent.type="image/*"
    appCompatActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"))
}
```

Comment: I will adapt and test. Also `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

What I gather, you need to create a screenshot of sorts of your view.
This is something I did a while back so I have some java code, not yet converted to Kotlin, but AS can take care of that.

You can utilise a class `PixelCopy`, unfortunately it is Android O +.

This is a simplified version of what you can do:

```
int[] viewLocationInWindow = new int[2];
view.getLocationInWindow(viewLocationInWindow);

int x = viewLocationInWindow[0];
int y = viewLocationInWindow[1];

int width = view.getWidth();
int height = view.getHeight();

Rect rectScope = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);

Bitmap screenshotBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Handler handler = new Handler();
        
PixelCopy.request(getWindow(), rectScope, screenshotBitmap, copyResult -> {
            if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                listener.onScreenshotSuccess(screenshotBitmap);
            } else {
                listener.onScreenshotError();
            }
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }, handler);
```

The `view` that is being referenced here should be your containing view. In my case, I had to take a screenshot of the entire view(the entire screen), so instead I did:

```
int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Then just implement the listener

```
public interface OnScreenshotTakenListener {
        void onScreenshotSuccess(Bitmap bitmap);
        
        void onScreenshotError();
    }
```

Inside `onScreenshotSuccess` you could modify the bitmap and do all of your other requirements.

Comment: To create a screenshot from a view in kotlin its even easier, I am using `view.layout()` and `return view.drawToBitmap()`